# Blank input field gives previous default value in $_POST

Tags: php

I am new here so hope I am respecting the protocol ;-)

Here's a simple issue that for some reason I cannot solve.

I have a form with post action calling a php file, and several text input fields with default values set. Example:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="profile.php">
<input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="q-2-Address" name="q-2-Address" value="Park Avenue">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
</form>
```

If I submit the form leaving the default value unchanged, `$_POST['q-2-Address']` contains the default "Park Avenue" as expected.

If I try to change the value in the input text field (ex: to "Madison Avenue") I can see the result in `$_POST['q-2-Address']` which gets set to "Madison Avenue", as expected.

But if I try to clear the value by removing all text, the `$_POST['q-2-Address']` is NOT blank and in fact goes back to containing the default value set initially "Park Avenue".

So if I want to update a form by replacing previously filled fields with blanks, this seems to be impossible, nor is it possible to detect that the field has been cleared. I tried testing using empty() but of course it gives a false result, `$_POST` contains the default value so is not empty even though the text field is empty.

Short of my entering something like a single space, I see no way of actually clearing a field.

It is a trivial thing but maybe somebody knows more about this.

TIA

Mike

Comment: @Muthu, for now imagine the code is simply: <?php echo $_POST['q-2-Address'] ?> .......  when the default value is replaced by nothing (cleared) the POST variable still shows the default value

Comment: OK figured it out. Thanks for helping. The example above actually does show a blank. I had some verification routines that were screwing up the values. My fault!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a default value in your form, you could use a placeholder...

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="profile.php">
<input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="q-2-Address" name="q-2-Address" placeholder="e.g. Park Avenue">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
</form>
```

That way, you can give an example of what you want to have in that particular input box, without the use of default text that will get picked up by the php code.

here's a jsfiddle of what the placeholder looks like.

http://jsfiddle.net/bfwst/

Comment: Placeholder is not supported in IE

Comment: You can get around that using jQuery tools like https://github.com/miketaylr/jQuery-html5-placeholder/blob/master/html5placeholder.jquery.js

Comment: Wow fast response.... What I am doing is displaying the content of a MySQL table, and allowing the user to update it, either by changing the content or deleting it.  If I place the current content in a placeholder, then again the user cannot enter a blank...  i.e. from the post I cannot tell whether the user tried to delete the content or left it unchanged.  So placeholder is not usable here...

Comment: If you're just echoing the $_POST variable as you said you are on the comment on your post, if the value is deleted it should be a blank... Could you post the php code as then it might be clearer what's going wrong?